# Create QGZ from Each Page Name of Atlas QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have searched about creating or exporting an atlas for each page nane to QGZ or QGS. But, I haven't found it. In the menu of QGIS, there are just pdf, image, and svg. Because I have to check and fix each page before I export to image. And there are many thing that I haven't known to automatically draw many item in the layout. SO, I will manually draw it in QGS or QGZ in each layout.

Does someone know it?

Comment: This would not be possible without programming some Python/PyQGIS code. What is the resulting project meant to contain though? Wouldn't it be better to edit the remaining things in something like Inkscape?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your task. You want to create a separate **project** for each feature of the coverage layer? What sense does that make?

Comment: You can copy-paste the project as often as your atlas featues has. That would actually result in the same output as you are looking for.

Comment: @Babel, No. I just want create project for each page name of atlas. For example there are 10 page, so the project will be 10 qgz.

Comment: @bugmenot123, I find using python. But it is for ArcGIGS. The link : https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/export-data-driven-pages-to-mxd/idi-p/975684

Comment: @MrXsquared, it will be time consuming, because so many page of atlas